# sort items by randomness

Tags: sort

I  have an e-commerce shop.
I am new to php and wordpress.
(I have a python and ruby background though, I just don't know php)

And I have a page with items. Right now the last 20 items  are displayed on page (or something like this).  But I want to show not the last, but items in random order from this category. 
This is code that lists items in archive.php file:

```
<?php echo category_description( get_category_by_slug('category-slug')->term_id ); ?></div>
<?php $col = 1;  $counter = 0;?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php ++$counter;?>
         .......
```

This code is not written by me. I clicked go to definition on have posts() function and got to this in wp-includes/class-wp.query.php

```
* @return bool True if posts are available, false if end of loop.
     */
    public function have_posts() {
        if ( $this->current_post + 1 < $this->post_count ) {
            return true;
        } elseif ( $this->current_post + 1 == $this->post_count && $this->post_count > 0 ) {
            /**
             * Fires once the loop has ended.
             *
             * @since 2.0.0
             *
             * @param WP_Query $this The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
             */
            do_action_ref_array( 'loop_end', array( &$this ) );
            // Do some cleaning up after the loop
            $this->rewind_posts();
        } elseif ( 0 === $this->post_count ) {
            /**
             * Fires if no results are found in a post query.
             *
             * @since 4.9.0
             *
             * @param WP_Query $this The WP_Query instance.
             */
            do_action( 'loop_no_results', $this );
        }

        $this->in_the_loop = false;
        return false;
    }
```

Also when I clicked go to definition it suggested me second option in file: query.php

```
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @global WP_Query $wp_query Global WP_Query instance.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function have_posts() {
    global $wp_query;
    return $wp_query->have_posts();
}
```

What do I do?

Comment: Do you need pagination? Random sorting of posts isn’t really feasible if you require pagination.

Comment: not really =just 20 random results from current category

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom query. [codex ref](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

For instance,

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

this query pick 20 random items. If you go above link, you can see more examples. I hope this will help you.